# can i use for loop in views.py in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

```
def index(request):

    answer_list = Answer.objects.order_by('-create_date')
 
    an_list = {}
    for i in answer_list
        an_list[i.id] = Answer.objects.get(question=i.id)


    context = {'answer_list': answer_list, 'an_list': an_list}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

```
for i in answer_list
                        ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I can get the right values in shell but in views.py,
I got the Error.

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a colon at the end of your for statement line ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)).

```
for i in answer_list:
```

Comment: you may be just starting out so if so, feel free to ignore, but there would be little reason to loop over the queryset like this to build a dictionary. You loop over 'answer_list' in your template.